# Создания массива

Tags: php

Здраствуйте. Подскажите, как создать из 2 существующих масивов с идентичной структурой один масив с вложенными масивами , чтобы в последствии можна было опять разложить его на 2 отдельных? Спасибо.

Comment: Пример до и после добавьте.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_A1 = [1,2,3];
$array_A2 = [1,2,3];

// Объединяем
$merge = [$array_A1, $array_A2];

// Разделяем
list($array_B1, $array_B2) = $merge;
```